# Как проверить подписан ли пользователь на определенный Telegram канал (Python / PyTelegramBotApi)?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, api, telebot

Пишу **Telegram** бота при помощи библиотеки *PyTelegramBotApi*, хотелось бы реализовать функцию ***проверки подписки пользователя на определенный телеграмм канал***, и если таковая отсутствует предложить подписаться. Зарание спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 5):

### *Ответили на англоязычном Stack Overflow.*

***Используйте метод **[getChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember)**, чтобы проверить, является ли пользователь участником канала или нет.***

```
import telebot bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN") CHAT_ID = -1001... USER_ID = 700...result = bot.get_chat_member(CHAT_ID, USER_ID) print(result) bot.polling()
```

***Вы получаете информацию о пользователе, если пользователь является участником***

```
{'user': {'id': 700..., 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': '', 'username': None, 'last_name': None, ... }
```

***или исключение если он не состоит в группе***

```
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400 Description: Bad Request: user not found
```