# Как проверять подписку на канал в телеграмм боте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

хочу, чтобы при /start проверялось, подписан ли человек на канал в телеграмме. есть видео для aiogram, но для telebot ничего не нашел

Comment: [Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1191929/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-telegram-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB-python) отвечали на похожий вопрос, возможно вам подойдет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как проверить подписан ли пользователь на определенный Telegram канал (Python / PyTelegramBotApi)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1191929/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-telegram-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb-python)